# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow - How to build String[] from a dynamic value

Tags: sharepoint

How do I build a String[] from a dynamic value?

I have an Initiation form that I collect email information and pass to my workflow as an Argument of type string

```
function StartWorkflow() {
 var wfParams = new Object(); 
 //build array of objects
 var emailUsers = new Array();
 //cycle through viewmodel emails
 for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.SelectedEmails().length; i++)
       {
                    var a = new Object();
                    a["emails"] = viewModel.SelectedEmails()[i];
                    emailUsers.push(a);
        }
  wfParams['strSelectedEmailsHMgr'] = JSON.stringify(emailUsers);


**This all works fine!**
```

IN my SharePoint 2013 workflow, I then create a dynamic Value variable called dvJSON.
Next, I add a ParseDynamicValue activity and set my variable dvJSON to my incoming argument    wfParams['strSelectedEmailsHMgr'].

Next, I add a WirteToHistory activity.
here's the result:
The value of dvJSON is [{"emails":"tom.daria@fhlbcin.com"},{"emails":"tom.daria@fhlbcin.com"},{"emails":"tomdaria@yahoo.com"},{"emails":"tomdaria@yahoo.com"},{"emails":"tom.daria@fhlbcin.com"}]

Next, I add GetDynamicValueProperty and set the ProperyName to "emails" source dvJSONa result reciepients (string array variable).

I then Deploy my solution.
When I start my workflow, I am presented with my custom initiation form.
I select my email users and click Start button to start the workflow.

The GetDynamicValueProperty fails.

Here is the error below.

```
RequestorId: d8a1f1c4-4b83-da9c-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Looking up a value using a key is not supported on an instance of 'Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicJsonArray'. at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicItem.TryGetValue(String key, DynamicItem& value) at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Thanks 
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to get exactly type string[], but if you need just to do something with each email value you can try use Loop for iterate through each item and inside the Loop use GetDynamicValue with argument '(iterator)/emails', where 'iterator' it is current index value, which you need manually increase on each iteration. 
As result on each iteration you will get new string value that will contain an email.